# How can I display a specific view in the main application template with EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Begginer with EmberJS, I am wondering how can I display a specific view in my main template ?
[image]

When I click on the menu in application.hbs I want to display User,Event
What is the best practice, using component ? moddal views ?
Do you have any good tutorial ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `{{outlet}}`'s are for. If you add a `/users` route to your router and you add a `users.hbs`. It will render this template in the `{{outlet}}` in `application.hbs`

See [this](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xuwayo/5/edit) jsbin for example.

Comment: Ok great, int users.hbs I have different views, e.g show a user profile, edit ... should I create a new template.hbs and /route for each view in my project ?

Comment: exactly you should probably read [this](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/concepts/naming-conventions/#toc_route-controller-and-template-defaults) it explains the naming convetions of emberjs they are **very** important. The rest of the guides are also a worthwhile read. Oh and remember _"if your interface is nested your routes should be nested"_.

Comment: One last thing, the modal views when should I use it ?

Comment: you mean modal views as in a dialog that needs to be closed or handled before you do anything else?

Comment: Yes exactly, `{{outlet 'modal'}}`

Comment: You should use them when you feel you have something that needs to be handled before anything else happens in your application.